# UITextView inside of PopoverPresentationController doesn't response to its delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uipopovercontroller, uitextviewdelegate

[image]

I am having problem making my UILabel to react to my UITextView by changing its textColor.

So when there over 250 words in my UITextView, my UILabel will should turn red. But it for some reason doesn't do it.

```
// class NewAppViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate...
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            let characterCounts = commentTextField.text.characters.count
            wordCountLabel.text = String(250 - characterCounts)
            if (250 - characterCounts) < 0 {
                self.wordCountLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                sendButton.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                sendButton.isEnabled = true
            }
     }
```

Comment: Did you specified delegate for uitextview?

Comment: I think I found the answer...

Comment: You must have missed adding delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being careless. I used UITextField by mistake. So now when I change back to UITextView, everything works fine.

Here is a picture.

[image]